# Append to value of data selector and then remove from it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to grab all data selectors named "data-step" from a given class, append to their values, and then restore them to their original value.
So basically, I want to change this:

```
<div class="MyClass" data-step="1"></div>
<div class="MyClass" data-step="2"></div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="MyClass" data-step="1 disabled"></div>
<div class="MyClass" data-step="2 disabled"></div>
```

and then back to:

```
<div class="MyClass" data-step="1"></div>
<div class="MyClass" data-step="2"></div>
```

So far, I know I can get all specific data selectors like so:

```
$( ".MyClass[data-step]" ).attr("data-step", "disabled" );
```

But this will rewrite the data-step and I will lose the original values.

Also, I am looking for a simple solution not using cookies or session storage.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

untested ... use jquery .each to iterate through the elements

```
$( ".MyClass[data-step]" ).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("data-step", $this.attr("data-step") + " disabled" );
});
```

---

```
$( ".MyClass[data-step]" ).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("data-step", $this.attr("data-step").replace(" disabled", "") );
});
```

> Also, I am looking for a simple solution not using cookies or session storage.

I have NO idea why you'd even consider cookies or session storage to make such a change

Comment: to be honest @ilian6806's answer is pointing in a better direction

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Also, as for why I would use cookies/session storage - I would not. It was a suggestion by a friend developer that I thought was strange, and I wanted to avoid getting it again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use other data attribute for disabled state. Like:

```
<div class="MyClass" data-step="1" data-disabled="false"></div>
<div class="MyClass" data-step="2" data-disabled="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Of course I could add an attribute, but that is not going to solve my problem and it was not what I was after. The reason this is not going to help is that the script that reads my "data-step"s doesn't read or care about data-disabled.

Answer (score 0):

changed the div to input to make visible the result :)

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {



        $('#btnDisable').click(function () {
            $('.MyClass[data-step]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
        $('#btnEnable').click(function () {
            $('.MyClass[data-step]').removeAttr('disabled');
        });

 });  
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="disable" id="btnDisable"/>
     <input type="button" value="enable" id="btnEnable"/>
 <input class="MyClass" data-step="1" value="111"/>
 <input class="MyClass" data-step="2" value="111"/>


</body>
</html>
```